# How do I navigate to next filter/search item in k9s?

Tags: kubernetes

When there's more than one search result from `/` filter command, how do you navigate to next item? Basically I'm looking for F3 (next search result) equivalent in k9s. Commands listed [here](https://k9scli.io/topics/commands/) does not seem to include what I'm looking for...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ok try your problem I created dummy 100 pods (2 deployments) in my local cluster :). 50 named test-deployment. 50 named test1-deployment. Used k9s to search with `/test?` and I noticed a mix of pods came up. To go further in list, donot forget to press `enter` key once you see your results and then you can use usual navigation like arrow keys or pgdn/pgup keys to move around the result. [image]

Comment: Neither enter key, pgdn/pgup nor arrow keys work for me.

Comment: This works when searching a list of resources but not when searching a description. When searching a description only the first match is highlighted.

Answer (score 12):

Narain's answer works when searching in a list of resources but when looking at yaml the interaction is slightly different:

1. Press `/`
2. Type search term, press enter
3. Press `n` to go to next, `shift-n` to go to previous match

Edit: I realize now that this is shown in the header. I suppose this explanation is good for other blind bats like myself.

[image]

Comment: What's mystery is that sometimes the header doesn't show "Next Match", etc. Not sure what's causing such behavior...